# I can't update my table in MySQL. Rows matched: 0 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have never had problems like this and I can't find the problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJBCK.png

1. CREATE TABLE setting_cube(i INT, subject VARCHAR(30));

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

2. UPDATE setting_cube SET i='1', subject='#uno';

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
> Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

and if I try:

3. SELECT * FROM setting_cube;

> Empty set (0.00 sec)

even though I have updated the table...
What am I doing wrong? thank youuuu!!!

Comment: You are trying to update data in an empty table. Populate your table (`INSERT INTO setting_cube ...`) and you will be able to update the data.

Comment: Exactly, your table is empty. What are you expecting to "UPDATE"?

Comment: --even though I have updated the table... -- but you didn\`t change anything

Answer (score 2):

The table is empty. You should insert some rows before updating them in the second step:

```
INSERT INTO setting_cube VALUES (1, 'first row');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create TABLE setting_cube(i INT, subject VARCHAR(30));
**----First you need to insert some x date**
insert into setting_cube values (1 ,'Test')
**---Now You can Update table**
update setting_cube set i = 1 , subject = '#uno'

select * from setting_cube